# How to get a reliable simulation of assignment delay in the always block (Xilinx Vivado)?

Tags: verilog, simulation, register, vivado, sequential-logic

I am having trouble with simulation of the nonblocking assignment delay in the `always` block.

A simple example: assignment of the input `in` to an intermediate wire `tmp`, which in turn is used to set the output register `out` on a rising clock edge.

As far as I know, in a hardware implementation of such a module, the `tmp` signal will switch almost immediately, i.e., in the same clock cycle as `in` changes. On the other hand, the `out` signal will switch one clock cycle after `tmp` (and this is what I usually observe on the ILA core). However, I am not always able to properly simulate this delay.

For example, I simulated two such systems in Xilinx Vivado (see the code below): `in1` → `tmp1` → `out1` and `in2` → `tmp2` → `out2`. The only difference is in the testbench: `in2` is generated using an additional `@ (posedge clk)` expression. The waveforms of `in1` and `in2` appear to be identical, but somehow they cause a different effect: `out2` does appear with the expected delay, while `out1` does not.

Additionally, if the intermediate signal `tmp2` is removed (and the assignment on a rising clock edge is `out2 <= in2`), the delay of `out2` also disappears. This makes me a bit confused, as I do not understand why such a simple continuous assignment would affect the timing to a degree that the delay vanishes.

I wonder how can this effect be reliably controlled. Specifically, I would like the simulated waveforms to work in line with the signals that occur in the hardware. This would speed up the debugging process as with minor changes I could rely on the simulation results, and it would no longer require re-synthesizing the entire project.

#### Simulation result

[image: Simulation result.]

#### Source code

**`test_module.v`**:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test_module (
  input clk, in1, in2,
  output tmp1, tmp2,
  output reg out1 = 1'b0,
  output reg out2 = 1'b0
);
  
  assign tmp1 = in1, tmp2 = in2;
  
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    out1 <= tmp1;
    out2 <= tmp2;
  end
  
endmodule
```

**`test_module_tb.v`**:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test_module_tb;
  
  localparam integer period = 10;
  localparam integer cycle = 2 * period;
  
  reg clk = 1'b1,
      in1 = 1'b0,
      in2 = 1'b0;
  
  wire tmp1, tmp2, out1, out2;
  
  always #(period/2) clk = ~clk;
  always #(cycle) in1 = ~in1;
  always #(cycle) @(posedge clk) in2 = ~in2;
  
  test_module UUT (.clk(clk), .in1(in1), .in2(in2), .tmp1(tmp1), .tmp2(tmp2), .out1(out1), .out2(out2));
  
endmodule
```

#### Schematic

[image: Schematic.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get unreliable simulation results because you have a race condition in the testbench code.  I was unable to reproduce your waves on 2 different simulators (I saw no delay on either output).

Although the inputs are changing at the same time as the clock rising edge, from a Verilog simulator perspective, they have a race condition.

One approach is to assume the inputs are synchronous to the clock.  In that case, drive the inputs in the testbench on the posedge of the clock and use nonblocking assignments, just like you drive the outputs of your design module.

```
module test_module_tb;
  
  localparam integer period = 10;
  localparam integer cycle = 2 * period;
  
  reg clk = 1'b1,
      in1 = 1'b0,
      in2 = 1'b0;
  
  wire tmp1, tmp2, out1, out2;
  
  always #(period/2) clk = ~clk;

  reg [1:0] cnt = 0;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (cnt == 1) begin
        cnt <= 0;
    end else begin
        cnt <= cnt + 1;
    end
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (cnt == 0) begin
        in1 <= ~in1;
        in2 <= ~in2;
    end
  end
  
  test_module UUT (.clk(clk), .in1(in1), .in2(in2), .tmp1(tmp1), .tmp2(tmp2), .out1(out1), .out2(out2));
  
endmodule
```

Now both inputs are synchronous to the clock.

[image]

I created a counter in the testbench (`cnt`); you can adjust it to correspond to your `cycle` parameter.